# ¿Como lograr que mi pagina web envie correos de manera automatica?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario donde los usuarios registran informacion sobre material que se convierte en scrap, y en base a esos campos, quisiera que mi sistema enviara correos, no solo notificando cada registro, sino tambien notificando en base a condiciones, es decir, si un registro es mayor a $200 dlls que envie un correo a determinada persona. Si cumple alguna otra condicion, enviar correo a otra persona. Intente utilizar la funcion mail() pero me marca un error con cuestiones de SMTP. Mi codigo es este:

```html
<form method="POST"  id="formA" name="formA" action="captura.php" autocomplete="off" style="color: #000">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
       <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 align="center"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Captura de Scrap</h4>
        </div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="fecha">Fecha de Reporte:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fecha" value="" style="cursor: no-drop; " readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="turno">Turno:</label>
    <input type="text" id="turno" name="turno" class="form-control" style="cursor: no-drop; " readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Línea:</label>
    <select id="linea" name="linea" class="form-control selectop" required>
    <option disabled selected value="0">Seleccione...</option>
    <option>L-02 (SMT)</option>
    <option>L-03 (SMT)</option> 
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="responsable">Responsable:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsable" name="responsable" placeholder="Jefe de Grupo" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">    
    <label for="noparte">No. Parte:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="noparte" name="noparte" placeholder="Ingrese el NP" onChange="buscar();" required>
   </div>
   <div id="resultadoBusqueda">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">  
    <label for="familia">Familia:</label>
    <select id="familia" name="familia" class="form-control selectop" required>
      <option disabled selected value="">Seleccione...</option>
      <option>Allison</option>
      <option>Toyota</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="dpto">Departamento:</label>
    <select id="dpto" name="dpto" class="form-control selectop" required>
    <option disabled selected value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <option>SMT Gas</option>
    <option>Final Assembly</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="fcmanufactura">Fecha de manufactura:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fcmanufactura" name="fcmanufactura" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for:"descripcion">Descripcion:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for:"costunit">C/U:</label>
    <input type="number" class="monto" name="costunit" id="costunit">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for:"cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
    <input type="text" class="monto" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" onkeyup="multi();" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for:"total">Total:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" style="cursor: no-drop; " readonly>
  </div> 
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12" align="center">
      <button id="submit" name="insert"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAceptar">Guardar</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Necesitas un servicio de SMTP google, aws, etc ... hay varios, ellos te dan claves para usar smtp, pero la consulta y la forma en la que envias esos correos todo eso debes verlo en el lado del servidor y el lenguaje que ocupues ahi php

Comment: Pero he intentado usar la libreria de PHPMailer y solo me alenta mi pagina.

Comment: Puedes usar phpMailer pero seguro que utiliza algun tipo de credencial los servicios de smtp no suelen ser gratuitos, por otro lado toda la logica de como quieres selecionar los correos en base a ciertas condiciones , debe ser programarlo aparte